# break while loop after list finishes growing

Tags: python, loops

I have a program that continuously prints a growing list of varied length in a while loop. eventually the list stops growing, and the program just prints the same list in repeat forever. once the list no longer grows, I want the while loop to break. Is this possible?

```
import json

terms = {'4837759863453450996': '"mamma riyoken"','4833480984509580996': '"mamma heika"','483775980980996': '"nemo heika"','4867568843796': '"control nemo"','4956775843796': '"t control"','483775843796': '"jared trav"','483843796': '"azu jared"', '483843996': '"hello azu"', '44384376': '"bitten virgo"', '48384326': '"bitten hello"', '61063868': '"charm feline voxela derp virgo"', '11136664': '"jessica"', '11485423': '"yukkixxtsuki"', '10401438': '"howen"', '29176667': '"zaku ramba char"', '36976082': '"bulma zelda dame prince"', '99661300': '"voxela"', '76923817': '"juniperrose"', '16179876': '"gnollfighter"', '45012369': '"pianist fuzz t travis blumt trav ttttttttttttttttttyt whole ryann lol tiper cuz"', '62797501': '"asriel"', '73647929': '"voxela"', '95019796': '"dao daoisms"', '70094978': '"mort"', '16233382': '"purrs"', '89270209': '"apocalevie waify"', '42873540': '"tear slash peaches attitude maso lyra juvia innocent"', '61284894': '"pup"', '68487075': '"ninja"', '66451758': '"az"', '23492247': '"vegeta"', '77980169': '"virus"'}

def _search(string):
    a = []
    for i in terms:
        i = json.loads(terms[i])
        i = i.split()
        if string in i:
            a += i
    for i in terms:
        i = json.loads(terms[i])
        i = i.split()
        if bool(set(i) & set(a)) == True:
            a += i
    return list(set(a))

def search(string):
    a = []
    b = []
    derp = True
    ret = _search(string)
    for i in ret:
        a += _search(i)
        a = list(set(a))
        while True:
            for n in a:
                a += _search(n)
                a = list(set(a))
                print(a)
            
print(search("charm"))
```

Comment: Perhaps `l = len(a)` between the `while True:` and the `for n in a:` and then where you have the `print` add `if l == len(a): break`. Not sure if you'll need to set a flag on that condition and use that to break out of the `for i in ret:` loop as well...

Comment: i think that does it!!!! thanks